# File size get too big when using array modifier

Tags: modifiers, vertices

I have a basic geometric unit '1.1.1mm cube' with the minimum vertex count that I could reach. I would like to duplicate it using an array modifier to make a X7,Y40,Z25mm bigger cube, 0.8mm offset. Although I've checked the merge option, and used mesh clean to merge vertices, the vertex count and file size get inflated, and the computer freezes. Anyone have better design ideas or solutions? You can download the file from this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11KlTY1PrDhpRBqAkAs8UabRv6ehmPYul/view?usp=sharing [image: unit]

Answer (score 1):

Your computer might be short of power for 5 million polygons, as I can make the array on mine OK.
[image]
You do have 211 unneeded vertices that you can get rid of by selecting one of them then Select -> Select Similar -> Amount of Connecting Edges, then press DEL and Dissolve Vertices

Also, your mesh doesn't look to be symmetrical so merging either creates holes, or, if the merge distance is set to 0.0, you get overlapping geometry. Here is a version of your cube that I have Mesh -> Bisected to produce the minimum unit. This can then be mirrored to generate your cube again. [image]

PS here's an outline showing one way to make a grid of tubes with geometry nodes [image]

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you so much paddyg for your help. Now I can run it much more smoothly on my computer.

Comment: Also, I don't know what your objective is overall here but you could probably make an array of intersecting pipes using geometry nodes, with bevelled curves.

Comment: Thank you for following up, my objectives is to build different shapes using this unit cube. However sometimes the outer struts have to be tapered from the first unit  upwards ⬆️… still thinking how to solve it. Can you refer me to a video explaining your 2nd method.

Comment: Could you please explain more about using "intersecting pipes using geometry nodes, with beveled curves" Thank you

Comment: my target is a bigger cube so that I can do a Boolean modifier on it to make tunnels with different shapes. Now it gets freeze when I try to  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X84FT0VCDkWTY4zepHBbqfAb37T9XWn1/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Hi @AhmedSamir I've added a blend file using a grid of curves. There's an issue with doing the four diagonal sets of tube as they need to be truncated at different lengths. Also the corners need fixing. But you might be able to think of something!

Comment: Thank you @Paddyg for your time. I tried to do it by it looks like it needs much work to find out. Instead, I used the previous methods and did a boolean modifier to a thin layer before duplicating it to get the target shape. thank you again for your help.